# Did Zeus become a literal ant, or a human with ant-like qualities, a worker?

Tags: zeus

The Myrmidons (or Myrmidones Μυρμιδόνες) were an ancient nation of Greek mythology. In Homer's Iliad, the Myrmidons are the soldiers commanded by Achilles.[1] Their eponymous ancestor was Myrmidon, a king of Phthiotis who was a son of Zeus and "wide-ruling" Eurymedousa, a princess of Phthiotis. She was seduced by him in the form of an ant. An etiological myth of their origins, simply expanding upon their supposed etymology—the name in Classical Greek was interpreted as "ant-people", from murmekes, "ants"—was first mentioned by Ovid, in Metamorphoses: in Ovid's telling, the Myrmidons were simple worker ants on the island of Aegina.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrmidons

Comment: What evidence have you found that makes you think it doesn't mean what it says?  Especially given the other myths of his seductions.